# How To Pass Datatable to Thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am studying threading in C#. I want to pass data table or dataset to thread in C#. Can i do that?
I have done couple of assignment where I can pass string or object or multiple parameters to function in tread but I want to pass dataset.

Comment: Why do you think passing a `DataTable` is different from passing the other data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataSet myDataSet = ...
Thread thread = new Thread(() => DoStuff(myDataSet));
thread.Start();

private void DoStuff(DataSet dataSet)
{
    ....
}
```